# How to load FileMaker Pro database into iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filemaker

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I create a database using `FileMaker Pro`. 
Can I somehow load it to my iOS app and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Export** the database to XML
2. **Write** a parser using `NSXMLParser` APIs that would load the data from the `XML` file and put it in a database/storage supported by iOS (e.g. Core Data).